# Gitblit blockpush hook not called

Tags: git, groovy, gitblit

I just edited the blockpush.groovy script in the groovy folder of the gitblit installation. I simply "return false;" in order to check if the script gets called. Also, in the test script, there is nothing written in the log file

```
Indicate we have started the script
logger.info("blockpush hook triggered by ${user.username} for ${repository.name}: checking ${commands.size} commands")

/*
 * Example rejection of pushes to the master branch of example.git
 */

def file1 = new File('C:\\workspace\\test.txt')
file1.write 'Working with files the Groovy way is easy.\n'

return false
```

What am I doing wrong? I am commiting and afterwards pushing

[image]

I was not paying attention that this code was the important part

```
 for (ReceiveCommand command : commands) {
        def updatedRef = command.refName
        if (updatedRef.equals('refs/heads/master')) {
            // to reject a command set it's result to anything other than Result.NOT_ATTEMPTED
            command.setResult(Result.REJECTED_OTHER_REASON, "You are not permitted to write to ${repository.name}:${updatedRef}")
            blocked = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your repository to use the blockpush hook script.

Comment: This does still not work, although I added the hook in the settings of the repo, please see image

Comment: @patentul this really solves your problem ? i have a similar problem

Comment: It's been a long time ago, I can't really remember how I solved the problem, but I did manage to solve it. Sorry, about that